# programmatically init a subclass of UITableViewController with a custom tableviewcell

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift, storyboard

Env: xcode6, swift

I'm trying to use [SLPagingViewSwift](https://github.com/StefanLage/SLPagingViewSwift) as the rootcontroller, and in one of the pages, I want to use a custom UITableViewController.

I don't know why it's not working, always throw"**2015-02-06 23:03:18.228 xiaoyu[4825:46536]  Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'unable to dequeue a cell with identifier PersonCell - must register a nib or a class for the identifier or connect a prototype cell in a storyboard'"**, and I have already defined identifier as 'PersonCell' in the storyboad.

Here is the code for main controlelr:

```
var controller: SLPagingViewSwift?

var ctr1 = PersonTableViewController()
var ctr2 = UIViewController()
var ctr3 = UIViewController()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()


    var navTitleLabel1 = UILabel()
    navTitleLabel1.text = "Home"
    navTitleLabel1.font = UIFont(name: "Helvetica", size: 20)
    navTitleLabel1.textColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
    var navTitleLabel2 = UILabel()
    navTitleLabel2.text = "Discover"
    navTitleLabel2.font = UIFont(name: "Helvetica", size: 20)
    navTitleLabel2.textColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
    var navTitleLabel3 = UILabel()
    navTitleLabel3.text = "Activity"
    navTitleLabel3.font = UIFont(name: "Helvetica", size: 20)
    navTitleLabel3.textColor = UIColor.whiteColor()

    var orange = UIColor(red: 255/255, green: 69.0/255, blue: 0.0/255, alpha: 1.0)
    var gray = UIColor(red: 0.84, green: 0.84, blue: 0.84, alpha: 1.0)


    ctr1.title = "Ctr1"
    ctr1.view.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
    ctr2.title = "Ctr2"
    ctr2.view.backgroundColor = UIColor.yellowColor()
    ctr3.title = "Ctr3"
    ctr3.view.backgroundColor = UIColor.blueColor()

    controller = SLPagingViewSwift(items: [navTitleLabel1, navTitleLabel2, navTitleLabel3], controllers: [ctr1,ctr2,ctr3], showPageControl: false)

    controller?.currentPageControlColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
    controller?.tintPageControlColor = UIColor(white: 0.799, alpha: 1.0)
    controller?.pagingViewMoving = ({ subviews in
        for v in subviews {
            var lbl = v as UILabel
            var c = gray

            if(lbl.frame.origin.x > 45 && lbl.frame.origin.x < 145) {
                c = self.gradient(Double(lbl.frame.origin.x), topX: Double(46), bottomX: Double(144), initC: orange, goal: gray)
            }
            else if (lbl.frame.origin.x > 145 && lbl.frame.origin.x < 245) {
                c = self.gradient(Double(lbl.frame.origin.x), topX: Double(146), bottomX: Double(244), initC: gray, goal: orange)
            }
            else if(lbl.frame.origin.x == 145){
                c = orange
            }
            lbl.textColor = c
        }
    })


    controller?.didChangedPage = ({ currentIndex in
        println(currentIndex)
    })

    self.setViewControllers([controller!], animated: true)
}
```

PersonTableViewController is the custom TableViewController, and in that controller, I have use a custom tableviewcell.

Here is the code for PersonTableViewController:

```
    override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // Uncomment the following line to preserve selection between presentations
    // self.clearsSelectionOnViewWillAppear = false

    // Uncomment the following line to display an Edit button in the navigation bar for this view controller.
    // self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = self.editButtonItem()
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

// MARK: - Table view data source

override func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    // #warning Potentially incomplete method implementation.
    // Return the number of sections.
    return 1
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    // #warning Incomplete method implementation.
    // Return the number of rows in the section.
    return 1
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("PersonCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as PersonTableViewCell
    cell.name.text = "aaa"

    return cell
}
```

Comment: Is there an outlet from your tableview (in storyboard) that contains the PersonCell to the table view you're trying to dequeue from?

Comment: Yes. The thing is if I don't use SLPagingViewSwift as the root controller, it just works fine, which means my custom PersonTableViewController is initialized by the storyboard, not by myself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `viewDidLoad` method should register the cell class with the table view. The method of `UITableViewController` is:

```
func registerClass(_ cellClass: AnyClass,forCellReuseIdentifier identifier: String)
```

So, in your case it would be:

```
ctr1.registerClass(PersonTableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "PersonCell")
```

Comment: Many thanks for your help. But seems it didn't work. After I added your method, it throws another exception "fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value", which pointed to " cell.name.text = "aaa" ", the name property in cell is nil in this case.

Comment: After I tried with "registerNib" in "viewDidLoad" function, it worked out. I don't know what's the difference between those two.